# Java creating an even ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static List subList(List l)
{
    List evenL = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
         if (l.get(i))%2 ==0)
         {
             evenL.add(i);
         }
    }
    return evenL;
}
```

Getting an error that % is undefined in this case. Not sure how else to retrieve an create a new list with even numbers.

Comment: I think you missed a small bracket in the if() line

Comment: Please learn how to write code which your compiler can compile w/o syntax warnings first.

Comment: @Smutje, I appreciate your concern for my syntax errors but as you can clearly see from my code I am new to working with ArrayLists and only now see how to fix it due to the help from others in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `)` as it's said before.

And your `List` is not parameterized with `Integer`.

```
public static List<Integer> subList(List<Integer> l) {
    List<Integer> evenL = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
         if (l.get(i) % 2 ==0)
         {
             evenL.add(i);
         }
    }
    return evenL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your `List` contain `Integer` types? If so you need to apply generics to the `List` used in the `if` statement so that [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) can retrieve the stored value

```
public static List subList(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> evenList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) { // minus )
            evenList.add(i);
        }
    }

    return evenList;
}
```

Comment: How about parametrize the return type as well? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` in the `if` statement. Change it to:

```
if (l.get(i) % 2 ==0)
{
    evenL.add(i);
}
```

If you're using  [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can use the `Stream API` and do the desired filter in a single statement:

```
public static List<Integer> subList(List<Integer> myList) {
    return mylist.stream()
                 .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
List<Integer>
```

otherwise the list elements are `Object` and you can't apply arithmetic operations to an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (l.get(i))%2 ==0)
```

should be

```
if (l.get(i)%2 == 0)
```